# Running Application from Qt Creator give an error QXcbConnection then Abort

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator

I'm building a game as Homework [reversitQT](https://github.com/mdahamshi/reversi)
,The project was working Ok in linux mint 17, when I upgraded to Linux mint 18, I imported the project to the Qt creator, and started to receive this error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

With the application abort as in the picture:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tATIs.png)

*** The built program run fine when I run it from the terminal**


**Old System Info:**

Linux mint 17  - 3.19 kernel

Qt Creator based on Qt 5.7

**New System Info:**

Linux mint 18  -  4.4 kernel

Qt creator based on Qt 5.8

Comment: Tried to valgrind it?

Comment: No. just searched for what it mean, and didn't find any relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a wrong configuration. Unchecked `Clear system environment` to solve the error:
[Settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HPgI.png)